# SKPSMTPMessage issue on Outlook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I´m using `SKPSMTPMessage` in my iPhone app and there is an issue with MS Outlook on Windows.

The email on OSX looks good. But on Windows, i have a problem with unicode characters.

---

**This is the way i use it:**

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           bodyMessage ,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

---

Is there an alternative API similar to `SKPSMTPMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a UTF-8 encoding somehow.

Change `kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey = 8-bit`

And specify `UTF-8` charset!

```
NSDictionary *plain_text_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"text/plain\r\n\tcharset=UTF-8;\r\n\tformat=flowed", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                 [bodyMessage stringByAppendingString:@"\n"], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                                 @"quoted-printable", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,
                                 nil];
```

Comment: Edited, src: http://skpsmtpmessage.googlecode.com/svn-history/r11/trunk/SMTPSender/Classes/SKPSMTPMessage.m